# Need an example for Add User to Group function in JIRA REST API 6.1

Tags: rest, jira-rest-api

I am developing an application that uses the JIRA 6.1 REST API. Can I know a sample JSON Object that I should use, to add a user to a given group in JIRA?

This is the relevant API call: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e1694

Comment: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/255778/need-an-example-for-add-user-to-group-function-in-jira-rest-api-6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl -D- -u admin:password -X POST --data "{\"name\": \"charlie\",\"password\": \"abracadabra\",\"emailAddress\": \"charlie@atlassian.com\",\"displayName\": \"Charlie of Atlassian\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://jira.server.com/rest/api/2/user/
```

[For more info see.](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e4133) Expand part under application/json, there you can find data example.

How to send queries, refer to [Atlassian's documentation.](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues)

Answer (score 0):

Came across this thread while looking to do the exact same thing.  The answer from @ThePavolC was very good, but it is creating a new user, not adding a user to a group.  I combined his answer with info from https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/255778 and came up with this one-liner:

`curl --insecure -D- -u *admin:password* -X POST --data "{\"name\": \"*username*\"}"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://*myjiraserver.com*/rest/api/2/group/user?groupname=*mygroupname*`

1. Replace *password*" with the actual admin password.
2. Replace *username*" with the name of the user you're adding to the
   group.
3. Replace *myjiraserver.com* with your JIRA server's FQDN.
4. Replace *mygroupname* with the name of the group to which you are
   adding this user.

I added the `--insecure` option because of the private SSL certificates used on my server.  You may not need that, or you may not be using HTTPS at all (in which case edit the URL to use HTTP).

Answer (score 0):

Please find below Python Script, I use to add new users to a group automatically.

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


BASE_URL        = 'https://site.atlassian.net'
groupname       = 'employees'
email           = 'jira.bot@domain.com'
jiraAPIToken    = '*******'
approvedDomains = ['microsoft.com','apple.com','facebook.com']
auth            = HTTPBasicAuth(email,jiraAPIToken)
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
query = {
    'groupname': groupname
}

def getAllUsers():
    """
    Fetch all Users account List including Atlassian Accounts (Approved Site Users), Customers, Active & InActive & Apps Accounts
    """
    global ActiveAtlassianAccounts
    ActiveAtlassianAccounts = []
    totalUsers = 0
    tchDomain_users = 0
    otherApprovedDomain_Users = 0
    inActiveAtlassianAccounts = 0
    customers = 0
    inActivecustomers = 0
    inactiveUsers = 0
    AppAccounts = 0
    startAt = 0
    while True:
        getAllUserURL = f'{BASE_URL}/rest/api/3/users/search?startAt=' + str(startAt) + '&maxResults=1000'
        response = requests.request(
            "GET",
            getAllUserURL,
            headers=headers,
            auth=auth
        )
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        totalUsers += len(data)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break;
        startAt += 1000
        for user in data:
            #Check & Add Active Atlassian Accounts, Only Approved sites users can have Atlassian Accounts
            if user['active'] and user['accountType'] == 'atlassian':
                accountId = user['accountId']
                if 'emailAddress' in user:
                    email = user['emailAddress']
                    userDomain = email.split('@')[1].lower()
                    if userDomain in approvedDomains:
                        tchDomain_users += 1
                else:
                    email = 'no_email'
                    otherApprovedDomain_Users += 1
                #print(accountId,email)
                ActiveAtlassianAccounts.append((accountId,email))
            elif not user['active'] and user['accountType'] == 'atlassian':
                inActiveAtlassianAccounts += 1
            elif user['active'] and user['accountType'] == 'customer':
               customers += 1
            elif not user['active'] and user['accountType'] == 'customer':
               inActivecustomers += 1
            elif user['accountType'] == 'app':
                AppAccounts += 1
    print(f'TotalUsers = {totalUsers}')
    print(f'Active Atlassian Accounts = {len(ActiveAtlassianAccounts)}')
    print(f'Technicolor Domain Users ={tchDomain_users}')
    print(f'Other Approved Domain Users = {otherApprovedDomain_Users}')
    print(f'InActive Atlassian Accounts = {inActiveAtlassianAccounts}')
    print(f'Active Customers = {customers}')
    print(f'Inactive Customers = {inActivecustomers}')
    print(f'App Accounts = {AppAccounts}')


def getGroupMembers():
    """
    Get existing users from group
    Loop through paginated results of group members
    """    
    global groupMembers
    groupMembers = []
    startAt = 0
    isLast = False
    while not isLast:
        getGroupMembersURL = f'{BASE_URL}/rest/api/3/group/member?includeInactiveUsers=True&startAt=' + str(startAt)
        response = requests.request(
           "GET",
           getGroupMembersURL,
           headers=headers,
           params=query,
           auth=auth
        )
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        isLast = data['isLast']
        for member in data['values']:
            accountId = member['accountId']
            try:
                email = member['emailAddress']
            except:
                email = 'no_email'
            groupMembers.append((accountId,email))
        startAt += 50
    print(f'groupMembers = {len(groupMembers)}')


def addUserToGroup(user):
    accountId = user[0]
    email = user[1]
    print(f'\nAdding {accountId, email} to {groupname} Group')
    addUserURL = "https://technicolor.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/group/user"
    payload = json.dumps( {
      "accountId": accountId
    } )
    response = requests.request(
       "POST",
       addUserURL,
       data=payload,
       headers=headers,
       params=query,
       auth=auth
    )
    print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))


getAllUsers()
getGroupMembers()

newUsers = [newUser for newUser in ActiveAtlassianAccounts if newUser not in groupMembers ]
print(f'New Users = {len(newUsers)} \n{newUsers}')


if len(newUsers) > 0:
   for user in newUsers:
       addUserToGroup(user)
else:
    print('No New User')
```